# iTunes video player doesn't work. Has anyone seen this screen when playing videos?

Tags: itunes

Every time I play a video or video podcast in iTunes, it looks like this:

[image]

The audio sounds okay but I can't see any video. I have this problem with pretty much every version of iTunes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Troubleshooting iTunes for Windows XP and 2000 video playback performance issues](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1386):

- Check your system requirements
- Update your software
- Increase Display Color Quality
- Disable Direct3D video acceleration
  in QuickTime
- Disable DirectX in QuickTime
- Modify your System Drive
  Configuration

The article contains detailed explanations with screenshots.
Although mentioning Windows XP, the advice given is still more or less correct for Vista & 7.

Comment: link doesn't work

Comment: I switched from Direct3D to safe GDI and that fixed the issue

Comment: @oo: Link fixed. You can undo your down-vote.

Comment: done with upvote